# Detect 0xff in multibyte word with bitwise operations

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

I have a 32-bit unsigned integer made of 4 bytes such as : `0x12ff3456`.

I'm trying to find a bitwise operation to replace the `0xff` byte by `0x01`, and anything else by `0x00` such as :

`0x12ff3456` => `0x00010000`

`0x543245ff` => `0x00000001` ...etc.

Only one of the bytes making the 32-bit unsigned integer can be equal to `0xff` at a time.
Does any one have an idea on how to perform this with the least possible amount of operations ? Folding (bitshifts + ands) would be an option but requires too many ops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple possibilities exist, and which one results in the minimum number of instructions, or the fastest execution time, will depend on the machine architecture and compiler being used. Some architectures offer an `ANDN`instructions, others support three-input logical instructions, still others merge shifts with logical operations. Below I am showing three variants that pass an exhaustive test.

The two approaches are to either base the output on a byte-wise equality  check with `0xFF` or a byte-wise "greater than" test against `0xFE`. These are selected via `FUNC_VARIANT`. The "greater than"  test is further bases on a "less than" test, for which two implementation variants are provided, selected by `LTU_VARIANT`.

The sources of the algorithms for clever byte-wise processing are noted in the comments. Generally speaking, a certain amount of masking is required in the intermediate steps to prevent the processing of a particular byte to affects neighboring bytes.

Note that the code can easily be adapted for processing eight bytes at a time, rather than four as the question specifies.

A quick check with [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) shows that with gcc, `FUNC_VARIANT=1`,`LTU_VARIANT=0` compiles to the shortest instruction sequences for both [x86-64](https://godbolt.org/g/kj9yxe) and [ARM64](https://godbolt.org/g/2r8KJf). This may not necessarily translate into the highest possible performance, though.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define FUNC_VARIANT  0
#define LTU_VARIANT   0

#define UINT32_H4  0x80808080U   // byte-wise sign bits (MSBs)
#define UINT32_L4  0x01010101U   // byte-wise LSBs 
#define UINT32_M4  0xffffffffU   // byte-wise maximum

uint32_t sign_to_bool4 (uint32_t a)
{
    return (a >> 7) & UINT32_L4;
}

uint32_t vhaddu4 (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    /* Peter L. Montgomery's observation (newsgroup comp.arch, 2000/02/11,
       https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.arch/gXFuGZtZKag/_5yrz2zDbe4J):
       (A+B)/2 = (A AND B) + (A XOR B)/2.
    */
    return (a & b) + (((a ^ b) >> 1) & ~UINT32_H4);
}

uint32_t ltu4_core (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    /* Sebastiano Vigna, "Broadword implementation of rank/select queries." 
       In: International Workshop on Experimental and Efficient Algorithms, 
       pp. 154-168, Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2008.
    */
    return (((a | UINT32_H4) - (b & ~UINT32_H4)) | (a ^ b)) ^ (a | ~b);
}

uint32_t vsetltu4 (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
#if LTU_VARIANT==1
    return sign_to_bool4 (ltu4_core (a, b));
#else // LTU_VARIANT
    return sign_to_bool4 (vhaddu4 (~a, b));
#endif // LTU_VARIANT
}

uint32_t vsetgtu4 (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    return vsetltu4 (b, a);
}

uint32_t vseteq4 (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    uint32_t r, t;

    /* Alan Mycroft's null-byte detection algorithm (newsgroup comp.lang.c, 1987/04/08,
       https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c/2HtQXvg7iKc/xOJeipH6KLMJ):
       null_byte(x) = ((x - 0x01010101) & (~x & 0x80808080))
    */
    r = a ^ b;         // 0x00 if a == b
    t = r | UINT32_H4; // set msbs, to catch carry out
    r = r ^ t;         // extract msbs, msb = 1 if r < 0x80
    t = t - UINT32_L4; // sign bit = 0, if r was 0x00 or 0x80
    t = r & ~t;        // sign_bit = 1, if r was 0x00
    r = t >> 7;        // convert to bool
    return r;
}

uint32_t func (uint32_t a) 
{
#if FUNC_VARIANT == 1
    return vsetgtu4 (a, ~UINT32_L4); // byte-wise a >ᶸ 0xFE
#else // FUNC_VARIANT
    return vseteq4 (a, UINT32_M4);   // byte-wise a == 0xFF
#endif // FUNC_VARIANT
}

uint32_t ref_func (uint32_t a)
{
    uint8_t a0 = (uint8_t)((a >>  0) & 0xff);
    uint8_t a1 = (uint8_t)((a >>  8) & 0xff);
    uint8_t a2 = (uint8_t)((a >> 16) & 0xff);
    uint8_t a3 = (uint8_t)((a >> 24) & 0xff);
    int p0 = (a0 == 0xff);
    int p1 = (a1 == 0xff);
    int p2 = (a2 == 0xff);
    int p3 = (a3 == 0xff);
    return (((uint32_t)p3 << 24) | ((uint32_t)p2 << 16) |
            ((uint32_t)p1 <<  8) | ((uint32_t)p0 <<  0));
}

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t res, ref, x = 0;

    do {
        res = func (x);
        ref = ref_func (x);
        if (res != ref) {
            printf ("error @ %08x: res=%08x  ref=%08x\n", x, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        x++;
    } while (x);
    printf ("test passed\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an exhaustive answer ! After further testing simple `if/else` branching is faster than bitwise solutions though, their combined instructions must be slower overall.

Answer (score 2):

The [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord) page explains how to get a mask where each zero byte is marked with the high bit set. You can apply this here:

```
((~x - 0x01010101) & x & 0x80808080) >> 7
```